# Validate some text in a ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to validate a text string to make sure it is safe. I do not want to escape it, as I want to display it.

I have tried

```
validates :description, :format => { :with => /^[\-$ ?!."'\/,a-z0-9]+$/i
```

and it works in that it passes text with characters that are allowed and fails when characters not listed above are include.

But Brakeman issues a message that advocates replacing the `^` with `\A` and the `$` with `/z`. However if I do this, the validator fails all tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working cause you are using forward slash`/` instead of back slash `\`. The `/z` means matching the characters `/` and `z` literally. It is `\z` or `\Z` And they mean as follows:

`\z` means the end of the string. Whereas
`\Z` means before an optional `\n`, and the end of the string.

So use the one which fits best with you!